# Changing PostgreSQL logic to Bigquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Im having trouble with this logic in Bigquery
PostgreSQL:
`SELECT  pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea('base64_byte', 'secret_key: text', 'cipher-algo=aes256')::text;`

I tried this in BQ to covert to BQ logic:
 `WITH EncryptedInput AS ( SELECT FROM_BASE64('encrypt_byte_from_base64') as ciphertext, FROM_HEX('secret_key: hex') AS key ) SELECT AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', key), ciphertext, '') AS plaintext FROM EncryptedInput;`

But BQ shows error:
`Failed to add a key from raw bytes: Unsupported key size: 18 bytes; expected 16, 24, or 32 bytes.; error in KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES expression`

What should I change in the BQ query to get correct result?

Comment: Hi @Hai Nguyen, Could you try using the query in the format mentioned in this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57730377/18329678) ? Let me know if this resolves your issue or not.

Comment: I tried that format at the beginning but no success. 
I think the problem is KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', key) is 18 bytes 
but BQ requires 16 or 24 or 32 bytes.
What should I do to parse the correct string to match 16 or 24 or 32 bytes?

Comment: Hi @Hai Nguyen, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The **[AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)** only supports the Key length of `128`, `192`, and `256` **bits** i.e., `16`, `24` and `32` **bytes**. As mentioned in this BigQuery **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/aead-encryption-concepts#advanced_encryption_standard_aes)**, AES uses a block size of 16 bytes, meaning that the plaintext is treated as a sequence of 16-byte blocks.  So, you have to change the encryption key length from 18 bytes to either of the supported key sizes(**16**, **24**, **32** bytes) to resolve the issue. You can also check the GCM and CBC mode of **[block cipher methods](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/aead-encryption-concepts#block_cipher_modes)** of AEAD encryption.

Comment: I ran this on PG:
`SELECT 
convert_from(
 pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea(decode( 'ww0ECQMCvmD7TU1IYYB90jsBsl+TfDLsose5dMdhewJv7AElMaz9tV6IqMU8Usd9UX/ShNRwe7AGyuOA1VBUs7CPwdwxdqF1BdxrQw==', 'base64' )
        , '1234567890123456'
        , 'cipher-algo=aes256')
 , 'UTF8')`
And PG showed: test123456

But when I tried on BQ, BQ shows error: 
AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING failed: decryption failed; error in AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING expression

Comment: WITH EncryptedInput AS (   SELECT FROM_BASE64('ww0ECQMCvmD7TU1IYYB90jsBsl+TfDLsose5dMdhewJv7AElMaz9tV6IqMU8Usd9UX/ShNRwe7AGyuOA1VBUs7CPwdwxdqF1BdxrQw==') as ciphertext,     FROM_HEX('31323334353637383930313233343536') AS key ) SELECT AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', key), ciphertext, '') AS plaintext FROM EncryptedInput; This is my BQ query. Sorry for my format.

Comment: Hi @Hai Nguyen, Have you changed the encryption key size to 16 or 24 or 32 bytes ? or is it still 18 bytes ?